# Delete multiple files or folders from a CSV file that contain more than one columns (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I need some help with script that will delete AD Disabled users Home Folders and Roaming Profiles folders on the Server (DC).
Steps That I already done, I create a powershell command:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Marked for Deletion,OU=Disable Users,DC=******,DC=com" -Filter * -Property * |
Select-Object -Property homeDirectory,profilePath | Export-CSV -Path .\Remove.csv
```

This Command export the properties of home folders and roaming profile folders of disabled users.
Now' the CSV file contains two colmuns, one is "homeDirectory" and second "profilePath"

[image: example]

The Problem is, when i execute this script, i get error.

```
$folders = Get-Content "C:\lab\remove.csv"

foreach ($homeDirectory in $folders) {
    Remove-Item -Path $homeDirectory -force -Recurse
    }
foreach ($profilePath in $folders) {
    Remove-Item -Path $profilePath -force -Recurse
    }
write-host -foregroundcolor yellow "Delete action complete"
```

Can somebody help me with this, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would remove the type information from your CSV like so:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Marked for Deletion,OU=Disable Users,DC=******,DC=com" -Filter * -Property * |
Select-Object -Property homeDirectory,profilePath | 
Export-CSV -Path .\Remove.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Then for your delete code I would use this:

```
Import-Csv "C:\lab\remove.csv" | % {
  Remove-Item -Path $_.homeDirectory -force -Recurse
  Remove-Item -Path $_.profilePath -force -Recurse
}

write-host -foregroundcolor yellow "Delete action complete"
```

The problem with your code is that you are not looping through a column, you looping by line and then doing it twice. To do it your way you would need to split the line at the comma.

Comment: Why remove the type information? `Import-Csv` is designed to handle exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
One more question, in profile folder i have folders named .V2
example:
\\lab\test\profilefolder.v2
\\lab\test\profilefolder
how to inculde in the script so they will be deleted too?